# How to install Cairo using Homebrew on Lion?

Tags: cairo, osx-lion, homebrew

I am trying to install **Cairo** using **Homebrew** on Mac OS X Lion, but I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_png_set_longjmp_fn", referenced from:
      _read_png in cairo-png.o
      _png_simple_error_callback in cairo-png.o
      _write_png in cairo-png.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [libcairo.la] Error 1
```

I thought it might be that libpng was missing, and it's included with X11 in Lion, so I added `ENV.x11` to Cairo's formula, this didn't fix it.

What's the next place I should look? Should I post more of the error/log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I **reinstalled libpng** using this package:  http://ethan.tira-thompson.com/Mac_OS_X_Ports.html, that solved the problem.